# Is it possible to propagate a Rose from a cutting?

Tags: roses, propagation

I have a rose that has suffered some wind damage.

Before it dies I would like to take some cuttings to propagate.  Can anyone advise if this is even possible and/or offer some guidance if it is?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. When I was pruning my roses last year, I had one of the elderly locals walk past while taking his daily walk, see what I was doing, and ask for cuttings so that he could.

Here's a fact sheet from a source I trust on how to do it: [Gardening Australia: Rose Rustling](http://www.abc.net.au/gardening/stories/s2634383.htm)

Having said that, your rose may not die at all. Mine survive being butchered; the one that suckered into the lawn survived being mowed (until I got around to moving it).